# Cannot access(SSH) to AWS EC2 behind family router

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using UBUNTU system, my ec2 instance is working fine, I can ssh to it with my mobile phone network. But when I use my home wifi, I cannot access.

When I type:

```
ssh -i x.perm user@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

it just hangs there, even <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> cannot force to recover.

I've checked my router settings, the settings should be fine. I don't need to use port mapping, as I assess to ssh server outside my router.

Any idea I can access my ec2 instance?

Comment: Try using verbose mode: `ssh -vvvi x.perm` might give you more information and tell you where it's hanging/why

Comment: @yegor256 Hi, cannot ping!!

Comment: @nickhar I run with that, and here is the output: debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0

Comment: @Eric Ah. Perhaps too verbose. Given that you can't ping it, wondering if your router is blocking connections on various ports.

Comment: Ping is blocked by default in most security groups, need to enable icmp in your security group to get a response from ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem.

The **router** I am using is not compatible with SSH cmd.

After I changed another **router**, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. I have the exact same issue. Noticed that my ssh was hanging on the same command. I tried a different router (used my hotspot instead of the belkin router) and voila... I was able to ssh without any problems. Do you or anyone else know if there's any other solution besides replacing the router?

debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0